# Django Profile Update on existing profile

Tags: python, django

I have the following signal for creating a profile when a new user registers and then sends an email to the admin informing them of the new user

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    '''Create a profile for a new user'''
    if kwargs['created']:
        Profile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def notify_admin(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    '''Notify the administrator that a new user has been added.'''
    if created:
        subject = 'New Registration created'
        message = 'A new candidate  %s has registered with the site' % instance.email
        from_addr = 'no-reply@example.com'
        recipient_list = ('admin@example.com', )
        send_mail(subject, message, from_addr, recipient_list)
```

I am looking to also notify the admin when a profile is updated but am struggling to come up with a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new function, decorating it with `@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile)` and then check is `created` is `False` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method -1**
As @Ralf said, use a different signal for **`Profile`** model and check the `created` flag

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile)
def profile_update_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # Profile update signal
    if not created:
        # do something here <<<<<<
        send_mail()
```

**Method - 2**
Override the **`save()`** method of **`Profile`** model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # your fields
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:  # not a new object
            # do something here <<<<<<
            send_mail()
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```